# How to update foreign key value when parent row is deleted in mysql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I want to update the foreign key value when parent row is deleted.

There is a **"SET NULL"** option in phpmyadmin, but instead of setting the value to null, I want to set it to something I want.

How can I do this?

Comment: You could use a trigger for this.  Can you include your table schemas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no auto-magical built-in way of doing this like the `set null` option, but you could always write a trigger with your specific business logic:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE TRIGGER parent_delete_tr
BEFORE DELETE
    ON parent FOR EACH ROW

    BEGIN
        UPDATE children
        SET    parent_id = 123 -- Or some other logic
        WHERE  parent_id = OLD.id;
    END; //

DELIMITER ;
```